# How to get spike values from a value sequence?

Tags: python, feature-extraction, preprocessing

I have pile of vectors where the values could be plotted like this:

[image]

Now I want to extract the "spike values" (over a certain threshold say 15,000). In this case there is fifteen. How could this be done with Python? (There is no predefined number of spikes but the threshold is a reliable filter value.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is very simple. Let's say your data in Panda format (named data_df), and extracting peaks/spikes over a certain threshold (e.g. 15000 here) is simply:

```
data_df[data_df > 15000]
```

If this data is sitting in a particular column, you can use this instead:

```
data_df[data_df['column_name'] > 15000]
```

These will return the peak values.

**Updated Answer:**

If you want local extreme points (e.g. maximum or minimum ) around each peak, check [scipy.signal.argrelextrema](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) in Scipy. A concrete example:

Let's make a artificial random data with random spikes:

```
import numpy as np                    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

random_number1 =np.random.randint(0,200,20)
random_number2=np.random.randint(0,20,100)
random_number=np.concatenate((random_number1,random_number2))
np.random.shuffle(random_number)
plt.plot(random_number)
```

[image: original data]

Now using *argrelextrema* function you will find the index of relative extreme values (either minimum or maximum)

```
c_max_index = argrelextrema(random_number, np.greater, order=5)
```

Please make sure you understand the "order" option. It basically look around 5 neighbouring points, and it returns the maximum in this case. And you can see how it works by pinpointing the found points on the actual graph like this:

```
plt.plot(random_number)
plt.scatter(c_max_index[0],random_number[c_max_index[0]],linewidth=0.3, s=50, c='r')
```

[image: original data with peak points in red]

Note that you can retrieve peak points via random_number[c_max_index[0]], and c_max_index are just indexes of the extreme points.

Comment: I don't want to get ALL values over the threshold but only ONE (the highest) values per peak. This is different.

Comment: I see. Honestly it was not quite clear this is what you want. Perhaps you want local maximum values nearby each peak. This is a different story. Please see the updated answer likely doing what you want.

Comment: You may like to check this example (just came across it today): https://github.com/demotu/BMC/blob/master/notebooks/DetectPeaks.ipynb

Answer (score 3):

As of SciPy version 1.1, you can also use [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) (data borrowed from [@Majid Mortazavi's answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/27033/63126):

```
import numpy as np                    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks 

np.random.seed(42)

# borrowed from @Majid Mortazavi's answer
random_number1 = np.random.randint(0, 200, 20)
random_number2 = np.random.randint(0, 20, 100)
random_number = np.concatenate((random_number1, random_number2))
np.random.shuffle(random_number)

peaks, _ = find_peaks(random_number, height=100)

plt.plot(random_number)
plt.plot(peaks, random_number[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

This will plot (threshold=100):

[image]

Besides the `height`, you can also set the minimal distance between peaks (e.g. 30):

[image]

In this case you would use (rest of the code identical):

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(random_number, height=100, distance=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement some sort of sliding window algorithm with with a window size of ca. 50 (according to your diagram) and then pick only the highest value within the window.